# how to append " in string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

for writing images on a html page i want to write only " after closing are anyone tell me about this then how i can write this

means to say that

```
<img src = " <% code is here %> " />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done like this, by escaping the quote with \"

```
String myStr = "Hello World";
myStr += "\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this syntax:

```
var s = @"a string with ""double quotes";
s += @"""";
```

Answer (score 2):

If using variable or expression use this:

```
<% string imagePath = @"c:\Images\wallpaper.jpg"; %>
<img src = "<%=imagePath%> "/>
```

If using statement use this:

```
<img src = "<% 

    string imagePath = @"c:\Images\wallpaper.jpg";

    Response.Write(imagePath);

%>">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

" is a special char. You need to prefix it with a \ otherwise it will interprete the " as the end of the string.

Details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To put double quotes into a string you have to escape them with a backslash.  E.g.:

```
String myString = "hello \" double quotes";
```